# Can GridBagSizer stretch when sizer item hide?

Tags: python, wxpython

When I use GridBagSizer and hide something1, space will appear.
Is it available to remove the space and stretch to top when sizer item hide?

```
sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(10, 10)

sizer.Add(self.something1, (0, 0), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.LEFT | wx.TOP, border=BASIC_MARGIN)
sizer.Add(self.something2, (1, 0), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.LEFT | wx.TOP, border=BASIC_MARGIN)
```

Comment: The problem is that it is still occupying position(0,0), you have not removed it, just hidden it. I'm guessing that if you removed it, you could tell `something2` to span the first 2 rows but then you'd run into grief if you needed to put `something1` back in its original posiiton.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I understand. Thanks.